# How to get zone and pod information using kubernetes api in golang

Tags: go, kubernetes

I am new to Kubernetes and I need to do some customizations using API's. My aim is to get pods from all zones of cluster or specific zones.  Using Kubernetes API and Golang I am able to get list of Pods and list of Nodes but i am unable to  find any interface which will give me list of Zones and interface which will give me list of Pods within zone.

Need guidance on how I can achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

You can get info about node Zone and Region by reading its `labels`. You can check out well-known labels here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/labels-annotations-taints/#topologykubernetesiozone.

You can build from this information about placement nodes in zones. Next you can `get pods` and filter the output by field selector.
Found example on GH: https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go/issues/410

```golang
nodeName := "my-node"
pods, err := clientset.CoreV1().Pods("").List(metav1.ListOptions{
    FieldSelector: "spec.nodeName=" + nodeName,
})
```

Comment: Hi Cloudziu.  We are planning to get node list first. From each node we will get zone and then we can get pod list by specifying field selector for node name as you mentioned. At the end we will sort out pod to zone mapping and achieve our requirement.